# Run program and set environment variable like in command line with awesome WM run

Tags: arch-linux, awesome-wm

I'm using prime for switching between graphic cards. The problem is that I need to set which card to use by setting an environment variable named DRI_PRIME when I'm executing the program. 
Example:

`DRI_PRIME=1 steam`

I could do that with dmenu but not with awesome's menubar or run prompt. 
menubar does nothing and run returns:

`Failed to execute child process "DRI_PRIME=1" (No such file or directory)`

Any ideas on how I can do this? I don't want to create scripts to run programs I prefer to do it on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `env` command to run a command with a custom set of environment variables, e.g.

`env DRI_PRIME=1 steam`